# Remove shapes from a map in D3

Tags: javascript, dictionary, d3.js, topojson

I am drawing a map with D3.js importing it from a topojson file.

In order to draw it I user the following code:

```
d3.json(input_file, function(error, data) {
  var units = topojson.feature(data, data.objects.countries),
  view = d3.select("#map_view");
  // ... SETUP OF THE PROJECTION AND PATH
  view.selectAll("path")
    .data(units.features)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", path);
}
```

This code will plots all the shapes defined in the input topojson file.
Now I want to remove few outlier small islands which I don't need which are located in a specified region in spherical coordinates.

Since now `units` object defines everything that is drawn, I tried to remove the shapes in the following way:

I identify the index of the country in the features list and index of the arc that lies in the desired region and remove the arc from the array:

```
var coordinates = units.features[5].geometry.coordinates,
    outlierId = 23;
coordinates.splice(outlierId, 1);
```

Now when I check the coordinates array of this country I see no arc with coordinates in the excluded region.

But it is still drawn on the map although the modified `units` object enters the `.data()` method. It looks like information about the shapes is coming from somewhere else. How can it be?

Comment: It's almost certainly going to be easier to modify the data before loading it with D3.

Comment: Yes, I guess so, once the arc index is identified. But I would prefer to do it programmatically, especially when the map is updated with some other, more detailed version, for example. And I still would like to understand why modifying the input to the `.data()` method doesn't change the output.

Comment: It's hard to say what's going on without a complete example.